# PowerShell script: Zip yesterday's log and move it to a network path

Tags: powershell, logging, zip, backup

I am new to PowerShell and I need to create a script (that will also work through the scheduler) that will:

-mount the network path as a drive (I think I did this with the code below)

```
#Machine hostname - needed for archive creation and identification
$hname = hostname

#Map network drive
$net = $(New-Object -Com WScript.Network)
$net.MapNetworkDrive("X:", "\\your network share\your folder",  
$false, "domain\user", "password") 

#Network folder where archive will be moved and stored
$newdir = "X:\your folder\$hname"
```

-Create a zip file with yesterday's log that has a name in the format:

```
$today = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
something_$today_something.w3c
```

-Save that zip in a temporary local folder

-Move the zip to the network path configured

-Delete the original log file

Any help finishing and optimizing this script would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify what version of Powershell and .net you have.  Zip functionality was built into .net 4.5, but previous versions required a third party zip utiltily.

Comment: PowerShell 2.0 and .net 4.0 (making software changes on the server is not an option).

Comment: Then you'll need to use a third party zip utility. What the script will look like will depend on which one you choose.  A lot of people like 7-Zip.  Personlly, I tend to use the dotnet zip library from Codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using dastardly com objects you could try the following for zipping up:

`$zipFileName = "c:\temp\logs.zip"

$shell   = New-Object -Com Shell.Application

New-Item $zipFileName -Type f

$zipItem = $shell.NameSpace($zipFileName)

$zipItem.CopyHere( "PathToYourLogFile",16)`

So if you have a folder full of log files you can run this

`$pathToYourLogsFolder = "c:\somepath"

ls $pathToYourLogsFolder | % { $zipItem.CopyHere( $_.FullName,16) }`

and then deal with zip and leftover files as you please. 
You can read more about *CopyHere* function on MSDN and this will not work on Win2012

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx